# Determine the size of each element in structure to use in qsort

Tags: c, structure, qsort

I'd like to know if the size of each element in my `Code` structure to pass to qsort is determined by `sizeof(Code)` or `sizeof(Code *)`. Either way seem to work. The same for `malloc(sizeof(Emp *))` or `malloc(sizeof(Emp))`

Am I doing something wrong on this sorting algo?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct CODE{
    void *ecode;
} Code;

typedef struct EMP{
    Code *codes;
    int total;
} Emp;

int *decptr(int n){
    int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *p = n;
    return p;
}   

int orderEmp(const void *p1, const void *p2){
    const Code *q1 = p1;
    const Code *q2 = p2; 
    int r = (*(int *) q1->ecode);
    int s = (*(int *) q2->ecode); 

    return (r<s)-(r>s);
}   

Emp *sortEmp(Emp *employee, int total){
    // sizeof(Code) vs sizeof(Code*)?
    qsort(employee->codes, total, sizeof(Code), orderEmp);  
}   

#define NUM 20
int main(){
    int i; 
    // sizeof(Emp) vs sizeof(Emp *)?
    Emp *employee = malloc(sizeof(Emp));
    employee->total = 0;
    // sizeof(Code) vs sizeof(Code *)?
    employee->codes = calloc(NUM, sizeof(Code));

    for(i = 0; i < NUM; i++){
        employee->codes[i].ecode = decptr(i);
        employee->total++;
    }   

    sortEmp(employee, employee->total);

    for(i = 0; i < NUM; i++){
        printf("%d\n", (*(int *) employee->codes[i].ecode));
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `qsort(employee->codes, total, sizeof *(employee->codes), orderEmp); ` and avoid using the wrong size.  Same for `employee = malloc(sizeof *employee);`

Comment: Thanks, can you please elaborate how this differ from the one posted? How would it break, segfault?

Comment: When I review `qsort(employee->codes, total, sizeof(Code), orderEmp);` and know that `employee->codes` is a pointer to _something_.  to get the size right, all that is needed is `sizeof *(employee->codes)` rather than `sizeof(Code)`.  I do not need to know the type it points to.  Less error prone.  Maybe tomorrow, `employee->codes` will be a pointer to a new type.  This way, the `qsort()` call needs no change.

Comment: Make sense, so with any malloc/calloc I should do the same then?

Comment: Since `sizeof(Code) == sizeof(void *)` and `sizeof(Code *) == sizeof(void *)`, you can get away with using either in this rather peculiar case.  In general, you need to specify the size of the structure — `sizeof(Code)` — and not the size of the pointer, unless you're sorting an array of pointers and not an array of structures.

Comment: The part that got me confused is `sizeof *(employee->codes) and avoid using the wrong size.` Does it mean that there is a chance to get the wrong size by not doing it as stated by chux?

Comment: @PeteDarrow, there is a greater possibility of *programmer* error if you do not follow `chux`'s advice, but such if you do not err then you don't have to worry -- at least until the next time the code is modified.

Comment: @JohnBollinger okay, thanks for the advice.

Comment: In other words, *you got lucky this time*, don't push your luck -- follow @chux's advise...